# handling multiple submits in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, submit

This is my code.

```
    <?php
    $qry5=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `questnTime`=curdate()");
    $quest=mysql_fetch_array($qry5);
    ?>
    <form id="form" name="form" action="">
    <textarea name="questn" id="questn" readonly="readonly" cols="45" rows="5">
         <?php echo $quest['questnId']; ?>.&nbsp
         <?php echo $quest['question'];?>
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option" 
         onclick="handleSubmit(this)" value="<?php echo $quest['optiona'];?>"/>
    <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option" 
         onclick="handleSubmit(this)" value="<?php echo $quest['optionb'];?>"/>
    <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option" 
         onclick="handleSubmit(this)" value="<?php echo $quest['optionc'];?>"/>
    <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option" 
         onclick="handleSubmit(this)" value="<?php echo $quest['optiond'];?>"/>
    </form>

   <?php
  if($quest['answer']==$_GET['option']){
  $option=$_GET['option'];
  }
```

Javascript code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function handleSubmit(current){
  var list = document.getElementsByName('option');

  for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    if(list[i]!=current)
      list[i].disabled=true;
  }

  alert('all disabled');
  }
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
  <style>
  input.myButton{
  background-image: url('option.png');
 background-color:#FFF;
 height:32;
 width:32;
 border-style:hidden;
 color: #FFFFFF;
   }
 </style>
```

What I require is when user clicks on an option all other options must be disabled. When an option is clicked, I want to get the value. Also I dont want the page to be refreshed. How to do this? The following code dosenot disable the options. Please help me!!!

Comment: For no refresh you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: @cohen Or submit the form into an iframe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case not make multiple submits put them as a button and when clicked then make all disable except clicked one and change input type as submit.